# Запрос на указание внешнего ключа через его атрибуты

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
  class_id integer NOT NULL,
  grade integer,
  letter text,
  PRIMARY KEY (class_id),
  UNIQUE (grade, letter)
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
ALTER TABLE public.classes 
  OWNER TO "user";

CREATE TABLE mainTable (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  class_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT readers_class_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY(class_id)
    REFERENCES public.reader_class(class_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
) WITH(OIDS= FALSE);
ALTER TABLE public.readers
  OWNER TO "user";
```

`mainTable` имеет внешний ключ `class_id`.

Я выполняю запрос на обновление:

```
UPDATE readers SET class_id = 1 WHERE id = 1
```

Программа получает пару значений `grade` и `letter`, которые гарантированно соответствуют значению `classes.class_id`.

Каким образом можно составить запрос, чтобы при указании в нём `grade` и `letter`, `class_id` в запросе получал соответствующее значение?

Очевидно, можно было избежать такой необходимости, заранее сохранив в памяти всю таблицу `classes`. Но в данном случае это подразумевает значительные временные затраты, которые я не могу себе позволить.

Comment: Сработало! Можете перевести в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE readers
   SET class_id = (select class_id
                     from classes
                    where grade=X and letter=Y)
 where id=1
```

Comment: Отлично. Только лучше сразу вместо "и" написать "and".